# random post redirect in wordpress with a .php file

Tags: php, wp-redirect

I saw a website let say `example.com`. Now there is a file called `go.php`. Whenever we go to `example.com/go.php`, we are redirected to a random post on that site. This happens everytime. That site is running Wordpress. Does anyone has an idea of:

1. Where is `go.php` located??
2. Possible code in `go.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that go.php is located in the root of the WordPress install.

The code in that fild would be something like this.

```php
<?php require 'wp-config.php';

$post = get_posts([
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
]);

if (!empty($post)) wp_redirect(urldecode(get_permalink($post[0])));
```

This is a wild guess but it does the job.

This code gets one random post.
If found post, get the post permalink (url), decode the url (good if you use other languages besides english) and redirect to that post.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! I just matched this with my condition and it's redirecting. But there's a problem. The first time, it redirects, second time too. For next attempts, it just stuck on the same post. Can you please explain why is this hapenning?

Comment: @AmanRawat How many times did you enter the `go.php` file. `'orderby' => 'rand'` always gets a random post, it can give you the same post from time to time. if you run the php function `rand(1, 10)`, you will sometimes get the same number back to back

Comment: OK, I got you. Thanks for the help, Buddy!☺☺☺☺